# Windows phone sdk 8 on visual studio 2010 ultimate windows 8 os

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, windows-phone-8

i installed windows 2008 on my system i had visual studio 2010 ultimate on my system.

is there any way to install windows phone 8 SDK on visual studio 2010 ultimate.

can i upgrade visual studio 2010 ultimate to visual studio 2012 ultimate.

i can download wp8 sdk but with that i am not able to develop web applications.

is there any way to download vs 2012 ultimate full version for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone 8 development. I got Visual Studio 2012 Professional for free via DreamSpark (www.dreamspark.com) because I'm a student.

You can get the free version:[Visual Studio 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads)

Comment: can i update my vs 2010 to vs 2012 because i am getting trail versions

Comment: I'm not sure but I think Visual Studio 2012 requires Windows 8.

Comment: it is a vs 2012 trail version or full version

Comment: Okay I'm wrong, VS 2012 supports other operating systems too. Take a look here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility

Comment: You can get Visual Studio as Express version. Just look for Visual Studio Express 2012 on this site: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads